# How display msg on dropzone.js in laravel 5

Tags: json, laravel

How I can display msg, after upload. I'm using laravel 5, and to upload - dropzone.js.
I try sth link this:

`return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);`

but its not working.

Comment: If you want to display a message after upload success you have to do handle it yourself. Take a look at [this section from the official FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#i-want-to-display-additional-information-after-a-file-uploaded)

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution, look at stackoverflow.com/a/66603779/5723524

Answer (score 0):

For errors: (quoting from the [official FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-an-error-returned-by-the-server))

> If the Content-Type of your response is `text/plain`, you can just return the text without any further markup. If the Content-Type is application/json, Dropzone will use the `error` property of the provided object. Eg.: `{ "error": "File could not be saved." }`

So all you have to do is this:

```
return Response::json(array('error' => 'Whooops something went terribly wrong'), 400);
```

Comment: Hmm according to the FAQ this should work. Anyways you could also try returning the message in plaintext: `return Response::make('Whoops something went terribly wrong', 400);`

Comment: still this same. Maybe server configuration problem?

Comment: Exactly the same? `[object Object]`?

Comment: Hmm. I honestly don't know what it could be. You could take a look at the server response in the browser developer console

Comment: http://img.nostatic.pl/img/a_5515d992729d5.jpg
Coud you tell me what I should do? Do You mean this picture?

Comment: Are you setting the 422 status code? because if not it's not even reaching the return statement in your code. That would mean the problem is something completely else... Try to google for error 422 in that case